# Where do I get hourly temperature data for cities with a high resolution?

Tags: temperature, open-data, urban-climate

I want to do a project with very high resolution temperature data from a city (any city) with very high resolution (<10 m), in an attempt to create an animated 3D microclimate map for that city.

The data would probably have to be raster data and it should be a time series of any kind (could be hourly but could also daily, the goal here is to test the 3D animated presentation). Where could I get such data?

Answer (score 1):

We used this site in one of the projects I did in a geoscience class. https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access The current site lists that there is a problem accessing information, but from what I recall the information can be obtained from any weather station across the globe under your parameters, and is compiled in a Microsoft Xcel spreadsheet that was easy to convert to ArcGIS, so would most likely be compatible in open-sourced ones if that is what you are using. Hope this helps.